# Device Fission Intel CPU

Tags: opencl

I'm trying to write an opencl program using the device fission extension.

I'm using an Intel i3 M350, but I'm not able to create sub devices:

```
#define USE_CL_DEVICE_FISSION 1

#include <iostream>
#include "CL/cl.hpp"

using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    cl::Context context;
    std::vector<cl::Platform> platforms;
    cl::Platform::get(&platforms);

    cl_context_properties properties[] =
    {
            CL_CONTEXT_PLATFORM,
            (cl_context_properties)(platforms[1])(),
            0
    };

    context = cl::Context(CL_DEVICE_TYPE_CPU, properties);

    std::vector<cl::Device> devices = context.getInfo<CL_CONTEXT_DEVICES>();

    cout << "Platform:\t" << platforms[1].getInfo<CL_PLATFORM_NAME>() << endl;
    cout << "Version:\t" << platforms[1].getInfo<CL_PLATFORM_VERSION>() << endl;

    cout << "Device:\t\t" << devices[0].getInfo<CL_DEVICE_NAME>() << endl;
    cout << "Profile:\t" << devices[0].getInfo<CL_DEVICE_PROFILE>() << endl;
    cout << "Driver:\t\t" << devices[0].getInfo<CL_DRIVER_VERSION>() << endl;
    cout << "ComputeUnits:\t" << devices[0].getInfo<CL_DEVICE_MAX_COMPUTE_UNITS >() << endl;

    if (devices[0].getInfo<CL_DEVICE_EXTENSIONS>().find("cl_ext_device_fission") == std::string::npos) {
        cout << "No device fission support!" << endl;
        exit(-1);
    }
    else {
        cout << "Device Fission: Available" << endl;
    }

    const cl_device_partition_property_ext subDeviceProperties[] =
    {
        CL_DEVICE_PARTITION_EQUALLY_EXT,
        1,
        CL_PROPERTIES_LIST_END_EXT,
        0
    };

    std::vector<cl::Device> subDevices;
    int err = devices[0].createSubDevices(subDeviceProperties, &subDevices);
    if (err != CL_SUCCESS) {
        cout << "\nError: " << err << endl;
    }
}
```

The output is:

```
Platform:   Intel(R) OpenCL
Version:    OpenCL 1.1 LINUX
Device:     Intel(R) Core(TM) i3 CPU       M 350  @ 2.27GHz
Profile:    FULL_PROFILE
Driver:     1.1
ComputeUnits:   4
Device Fission: Available

Error: -1057
```

This error code stands for:

> CL_DEVICE_PARTITION_FAILED_EXT                  -1057
>
> ```
> Returned by clCreateSubDevicesEXT when the total number of compute units
> requested exceeds CL_DEVICE_MAX_COMPUTE_UNITS, or the number of compute
> units for any one sub-device is less than 1.
> ```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3):

First of all, the best place to ask questions about the Intel OpenCL SDK implementation is their (our) forum: 
http://software.intel.com/en-us/forums/intel-opencl-sdk/

That being said, the current version has some quirks around the implementation of clCreateSubdevicesEXT. The one you seem to be running into is that it expects the last parameter in the C API, num_devices_ret, to be a non-NULL pointer pointing to the amount of resultant sub-devices. The C++ wrapper is apparently unfamiliar with this issue and thus you get that failed return value.

I'm not very familiar with the C++ wrapper so I don't know whether you can force it to pass a non-NULL pointer in the underlying call to clCreateSubdevicesEXT. Assuming you can't, potential solutions are to modify the wrapper yourself, or to use the C API.

Future revisions of the SDK will be less finicky about such things; In the one you have, it's more of a preview feature.

Comment: You're right, since it is Intel specific it belongs there. I posted it over there as well. For the ones following the thread here: I used C to test it, but am constantly getting `[appname]: symbol lookup error: [appname]: undefined symbol: clCreateSubDevicesEXT`.

Answer (score 1):

have your tried any of the Khronos examples from http://www.khronos.org/registry/cl/extensions/ext/cl_ext_device_fission.txt

Like:

Example: to split a four compute unit device into two sub-devices, 
            each containing two compute units, pass:

```
            { CL_DEVICE_PARTITION_BY_COUNTS_EXT, 
              2, 2, CL_PARTITION_BY_COUNTS_LIST_END_EXT,
              CL_PROPERTIES_LIST_END_EXT }
```

Comment: Thanks, the link is useful. However I had tried the above partition as well. Could it be hardware-related?